# How can I avoid a warning in a child class due to attribute covariance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to avoid the linter warning that is shown as a comment in the last line of the code sample.

I understand why it happens, and I know I could very well ignore because this is Python. But as a sort of self-exercise, I've been trying to think of a properly typed way to avoid it, and haven't been able to find a solution.

Here's a code sample:

```py
class Content(ABC):
    def __init__(self, data: Dict):
        self._data: Dict = data


class AlertContent(Content):
    def __init__(self, alert: Alert):
        data: Dict = get_data_from_alert(alert)
        super().__init__(data)
        self.alert_priority: str = alert.priority


class Envelope(ABC):
    def __init__(self, content: Content):
        self._content: Content = content
    
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def priority(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError


class AlertEnvelope(Envelope):
    def __init__(self, content: AlertContent):
        super().__init__(content)

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def priority(self) -> str:
        return self._content.alert_priority  # Warning: Unresolved attribute reference 'alert_priority' for class 'Content'
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The type of `_content` is `Content`, not `AlertContent`. So it might not have an `alert_priority` attribute.

Comment: The linter can't tell that `AlertEnvelope().__init__()` dynamically ensures that `self._content` will be `AlertContent`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. As I said in the question body, I do understand why the error happens, and I agree with the linter warning. What I was asking was if there was some way I could refactor this code so the warning didn't appear because everything's everything properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going for the following solution:

```py
class AlertEnvelope(Envelope):
    def __init__(self, content: AlertContent):
        super().__init__(content)

    # Inherited from Envelope
    # @property
    # def content(self) -> Content:
    #     return self._content

    def alert_content(self) -> AlertContent:
        return cast(AlertContent, self._content) # ** Reasoning below 

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def priority(self) -> str:
        return self.alert_content.alert_priority
```

** The reasons for the solution I chose are:

1. Even though `cast` doesn't do literally anything (defined as `pass`), it's a way for linters to know that something has changed in the typing, so you don't get an error. And, being `pass`, its cost is almost negligible.
2. Explicitness for anyone that reads the code that something's going on.
3. Mimics the way you'd do it in C++, a hard typed language, which kinda was one of my goals, to follow a hard typing approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets into a matter of style, but it's arguable that since having accurate typing is part of your design, that you don't actually want `super().__init__(content)` because you're constructing a class that relies on the concrete interface of `AlertContent`, while the parent class explicitly types the attribute with the more abstract type that does not implement the interface.

Thus,

```
class AlertEnvelope(Envelope):
    def __init__(self, content: AlertContent):
        self._content: AlertContent = content
```

might still be DRY code, considering what your goal is.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but I don't know what to think of overriding the attribute types (and properties as well) in the children classes.